# Keras gives 'Not JSON Serializable' when saving DCN model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am following the tutorial here to build a DCN model https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/dcn

I tried to save the model and make predictions later.

Approach 1:

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, "features")

loaded = tf.saved_model.load("features/")
```

This loaded model do not have `predict` method.

Approach 2:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, "features")
```

Then it raised an error

```
'Not JSON Serializable:', b'156602'
```

Any suggestions on how to save a DCN model?

tensorflow == 2.6.2

Comment: It seems like you do need to compile the model before loading the weights on it, probably because you only saved the trained weights